# Gatsby | React component flashes when updating form

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am running a gatsby app / react with styled-component and I have a form and everytime I update a value in the form it will quickly flash the screen even the nav items will flash very quickly. It is very jarring and I am looking at how to solve it. I have looked around the console with no errors and also looked for anything that would look like an error in the react app and I can't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached a link to show what I mean.

https://gist.github.com/dkbollig/8cff76519cb355d1806b7bf263f2823a

[Example of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuBPC.jpg)

Comment: What does clicking one of the checkboxes do as far as updating state, and what UI elements depend on that state to change etc. Need more info and relevant code.

Comment: This could originate from a variety of reasons. One of which could be related to a misguided use of useEffect (check out useLayoutEffect). Please add some relevant code so we can get more info.